# PG error on running rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

On running my rails application I am getting the follwoing error

```
PGError (could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.1024"?
):
```

I tried the command

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

I am getting the following:

```
Stopping postgresql service:                               [FAILED]
Initializing database: mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log': File exists
                                                           [FAILED]
Starting postgresql service:                               [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is not connected with Ruby on Rails. You should check permissions for PostgreSQL log directory. Also you need to be sure that you are starting Postgres daemon as root:

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```